# Como reconstruir todos los Indices de una base de datos en sql server?

Tags: sql-server, windows, tsql

Desde hace una semana he tenido problemas con el sistema ... mandaba error de timeout, sacaba de la sesiones a los usuarios, hasta que recorde, si al log nunca le dieron mantenimiento .. mucho menos revisaron los indices .. se hacerlo con una tabla pero quisiera revisar toda la base de datos ... después reorganizar y reconstruir estos y esperar a que con eso funcione mucho mejor el sistema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo. Si no tienes mucha experiencia te recomiendo utilizar alguna de las soluciones que ya existen para hacerlo y que han sido validadas por miles de DBAs alrededor del mundo. Dejo 2 opciones muy populares:

- [Solución de Mantenimiento de Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)
- [Minionware Reindex](http://www.minionware.net/products/reindex/)

Ambas soluciones las puedes estudiar y modificar según tus necesidades, pero es poco probable que necesites modificarlas. De ambas puedes aprender bastante.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! los he corrido a la perfección con Ola Hallegren y redujo bastante el tiempo de ejecución de los querys